# How to use UIKeyboardImpl.isInHardwareKeyboardMode

Tags: ios, swift, uikeyboard, iphone-privateapi

I want to detect whether an external keyboard has been attached to the lightning port. I've read other answers about listening to the soft keyboard `keyboardDidHide/Show`, but that's not what I want to do. I want to know how to use this private API..

I found this on GitHub https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/tree/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework but when I tried just copying the `UIKeyboardImpl` class over, I ran into a bunch of compile error.
Any suggestion on how to import this class so I could use it? Thanks.

Comment: Using private APIs is a bad idea, since it will get your app rejected from the AppStore

Comment: Understood and I'm not submitting to the store, so I don't really care. I just want to know how this works.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code: https://gist.github.com/myell0w/d8dfabde43f8da543f9c

Since it uses objc_msgSend to interact with the private class, you don't need to mess about with any private header files.

Just add this to the top of your file to get it to work:

`#import <objc/message.h>`